# Flutter - How to retrieve an implemented class with Get.find after registered with Get.put using GetX?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a class called GetConnectApiHelper that implemented an abstraction called IApiHelper, I need to register this class with Get.put inside Bindings and retrieve the implementation inside an abstraction variable but when I try to do that I get an error about "the abstraction is not registered".

How can I inject the dependency correctly making it easy to change in case I need to replace with http, dio etc...(clean architecture)

```
abstract class IApiHelper {}

class GetConnectApiHelper extends GetxService implements IApiHelper {}

class SignInBinding extends Bindings {

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(GetConnectApiHelper());
    Get.put(SignInController());
  }

}

class SignInController extends GetxController {

  final IApiHelper apiHelper = Get.find(); // This throws the exception

}

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following message was thrown building Builder(dirty):
"IApiHelper" not found. You need to call "Get.put(IApiHelper())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>IApiHelper())"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. I can set the Interface as a Type and then register the implementation I want to be retrieved.

```
class SignInBinding extends Bindings {

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<IApiHelper>(GetConnectApiHelper());
    Get.put(SignInController());
  }

}

class SignInController extends GetxController {

    final IApiHelper apiHelper = Get.find();

}

print(apiHelper.runtimeType); // it prints Instance of 'GetConnectApiHelper'
```

Or I can inject the implementation.

```
class SignInBinding extends Bindings {

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<IApiHelper>(GetConnectApiHelper());
    Get.put(SignInController(apiHelper: Get.find()));
  }

}

class SignInController extends GetxController {

    final IApiHelper apiHelper;
    SignInController({required this.apiHelper})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetX finds its dependencies based on its exact types so you need to use `Get.find<GetConnectApiHelper>()`

updated:

```
class SignInBinding extends Bindings {

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(GetConnectApiHelper());
    Get.put(SignInController<GetConnectApiHelper>());
  }

}

class SignInController<T extends IApiHelper> extends GetxController {

  final IApiHelper apiHelper = Get.find<T>(); 

}
```

Comment: Ok, but in case I need to change my http client I will need to update all dependencies declared in the Bindings class and in each Get.find<New_Dependency_here>()?

Comment: I updated the answer, I think it's the only way

Comment: I found a solution but thank you very much.